# Spread Betting API?

Tags: java, rest

Does anyone know of any Java or REST API for any Financial Markets Spread Betting provider?

I want to automate opening and closing of positions in stocks listed on the S&P 500 etc.

Failing a defined API - does anyone know of any Spread Betting providers that have a simple Web API that could be easily automated via a Web Robot of some sort?

Comment: A quick google comes up with [prospreads](http://www.prospreads.com/index.php?fb).

Comment: https://github.com/cityindex/CIAPI.Java

Answer (score 0):

IG Group have a cfd and spreadbet API. https://labs.ig.com/

The API provides REST-based and streaming access to a range of asset classes (including indices, forex, commodities, binaries and options), and includes functionality to:

- Trade using risk management tools such as stops and limits
- View real-time and historical market prices
- Analyse market instrument and client sentiment information
- Review account balances and trade history